# Can breadcrumb placement below main menu as shown cause a confusion to user?

Tags: navigation

Is this the best way to display user navigation path in modern UX?
If user navigation path is too long for one line, can breadcrumb be split across second line ?
If not is there any alternative available in modern UX ?

Also my websites menu is directly above the breadcrumb, will this cause any confusion to the user? Is there any alternative placement for the breadcrumb ?

Some templates prefer to show the breadcrumb at right side of the page but the application for which we are planning this feature might contain long names.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use truncation to allow longer titles and deeper nesting. It also works when you have a smaller viewport.

Assuming you may have some deep hierarchies and perhaps long titles, you can start truncating the links to allow users to still see (and select) to navigate back up the hierarchy.

[image]

This pattern can be seen in Google Drive.

Comment: Great! that seems like a good approach for long titles and deeper nesting.

Comment: My website menu is directly above the breadcrumb, can this cause any confusion for the user ? Can you suggest something about this ?